# Getting 403 error while scraping a website page for data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-scraping

I have a price comparison website which scrapes prices from various websites. For all websites the code is working fine but one is returning 403 forbidden error. The website is developed in Asp.net MVC3 framework. Following is my code.

```
public static decimal? GetSpanFromWebSite(string url, string identification)
    {
        var baseUrl = new Uri(url);
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
        try
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            document.Load(client.OpenRead(baseUrl));
            var div = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(identification).FirstOrDefault();
            return Convert.ToDecimal(div.InnerHtml);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

What is the workaround and how can i continue scrapping the website?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a scraping countermeasure implemented by the site.

Try to mimick the browser request as closely as possible (especially headers - user agent, referer, content-type etc.)

Comment: i am not sure how to do it...I am using the code stated in the question and it handles everything

Answer (score 0):

**403 Forbidden**
Actually server is understanding and accepting your request at the same time the server is denying your request, so check your HttpRequest Headers and Cookie values

you can use web debugging tool like fiddler http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-debugging
to debug the request and response